# Cannot Insert Data from Combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I cannot insert data from a combobox.

I have 3 combobox that affect each other.

If `combobox1` is not null, than `combobox2` will show a value that need it but it can be null, if `combobox2` is not null, than `combobox3` show value that need it same here.

So I have tried insert it, if all combobox have a value then data can be inserted, if combobox 1 and 2 have a value I can insert it too, but when combobox 2 & 3 don't have a value, then it doesn't want to input.

I'm using `After Update` event.

In my case, I have to input a License that not all of them have a group, and not all of them have a subgroup. So it inserts it as blank or empty string (`""`). I've search reference in here, but I have no clue.

Many thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub cmb1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cmb2.RowSource = ""
    Me.cmb2.Value = ""
    Me.cmb3.RowSource = ""
    Me.cmb3.Value = ""

    Dim strSQL As String

    If IsNull(cmb1) = False Then
        strSQL = "Select ID_Group " & _
        "From Tbl_Mst_Group " & _
        "Where ID_License = '" & Me.cmb1 & "'"

        Me.cmb2.RowSource = strSQL
        Me.cmb2.Requery
     Else
        Me.cmb2.RowSource = ""
        Me.cmb2.Value = ""
        Me.cmb3.RowSource = ""
        Me.cmb3.Value = ""
    End If

Private Sub cmb2_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strSQL As String

    If IsNull(cmb2) = False Then
        strSQL = "Select ID_SubGroup " & _
                 "From Tbl_Mst_SubGroup " & _
                 "Where ID_Group = '" & Me.cmb2 & "'"
        Me.cmb3.RowSource = strSQL
        Me.cmb3.Requery
    Else
        Me.cmb3.RowSource = ""
        Me.cmb3.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the issue ?

Comment: There is no error, but I cant insert the value when combobox is empty, my table contain column name License and it has relationship with table group and table group has relationship with subgroup, but not all License has group and subgroup. So I just want let it empty. this is my problem  if all combobox  1,2 & 3 have value, data can be insert, if combobox 1 and 2 have value it can insert it too, but when combobox 2 & 3 don't have value, it wont insert with no error. I just think is it because may event after update?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your Form is bound to a table and the ComboBoxes are bound to  columns of this table. If the columns are marked as `Required`, the they cannot be `Null`. Therefore make the columns for ComboBox 2 & 3 `Required = No` .

Another problem is that if you want them to be empty, you must assign them `Null` instead of an empty string (`""`).

```
Me.cmb2.RowSource = ""
Me.cmb2.Value = Null
Me.cmb3.RowSource = ""
Me.cmb3.Value = Null
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I've tried, but still same can not insert while combo 2& 3 empty

Comment: If you are getting an error message, what is the exact message?

Comment: There's no error sir, when I click on add button, it's just nothing happen. Then when I refresh the table, it's still not insert the data

Comment: That's a case for debugging. We cannot do this for you.